# XHTML: CSS does not display?

Tags: css, google-chrome, opera, xhtml-1.1

Not sure entirely what is happening, but I get the following errors from Internet Explorer and Google Chrome...yet it displays perfectly in Opera >_>

### Google

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.

### IE

IE renders the page but doesn't apply ANY of the tags and just displays the text >_>

## Code

### XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<!-- This is a redesign of my redesign -->
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Hello</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fonts.css" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/container.css"/>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/banner.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Container">
            <div id="Banner"></div>
            <div id="Content"><p>Hello World</p></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### CSS Example

```
@charset “UTF-8?";
/*CSS for the Container and non div items*/
#Container {
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 600px;
    max-height: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1%;
    z-index: 0;
}
#Content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;        
    min-height: 70%;
    height: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 2;
    border-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

What gives O_o

Comment: FYI, 1) XHTML 1.1 is a dormant standard 2) The full stop in English is ".", not ">_>", and the question mark is "?", not "O_o".

Comment: Grammar Nazi alert!!!!! But XHTML according to w3c is the future for HTML4...

Comment: It *was* about 10 years ago, but HTML5 is the cool new thing now.

Comment: http://webdesign.about.com/b/2009/07/06/goodbye-xhtml-hello-html-5.htm  apparently the w3c need to update their 'preferred doctypes' >_> <_<. *happy?*

Comment: Did you try changing the doctype to HTML5? (See, how I used the question mark there?)

Comment: @BoldClock Most browsers support XHTML now, even IE. So it's a de facto standard! And yes, HTML is the new rage now, but not everybody wants to partake in the new rage. Some of us like to wait in the sidelines until the insanity blows over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XHTML file *MUST* have the xmlns attribute `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` in its html start tag or it will not be recognised as XHTML.

Opera's behaviour is non-standard.

Comment: That's interesting. I never had a page give me any issues when I didn't include that.

Comment: That...would indeed cover it O_O thank you muchly. Although slightly irrelevant due to my recent discovery that XHTML1.1 is 'not' the way forwards ._.; That won't stop me looking for XHTML5 though n_n.

Comment: @AlexMorales Only XHTML files that are served up with some kind of XML MIME type (like `application/xhtml+xml`) are treated as XML (and therefore need an explicit namespace). Otherwise they're ordinary HTML, no matter the DOCTYPE declaration!

Comment: You can still write your HTML5 documents as if they were XHTML. You just can't serve them up as xml. And yeah, Lister, I forgot about that O_O

Answer (score 0):

The first line in your CSS file looks wrong:

```
@charset “UTF-8?;
```

Should probably be:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

Comment: A UTF-8 document that isn't correctly encoded as UTF-8? Blasphemy!

Comment: Yeah I caught that one, made no difference. Adding the UTF-8 itself was an effort to fix the problem.